# Why is taking the address of a destructor forbidden?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, standards

C++ standard at 12.4.2 states that

> [...] The address of a destructor shall not be taken. [...]

However, one can without any complaints by the compiler take the address of a wrapper around a class destructor, like this:

```c++
struct Test {
    ~Test(){};

    void destructor(){
        this->~Test();
    }
};

void (Test::*d)() = &Test::destructor;
```

So what's the rationale behind forbidding to take the address of a destructor directly?

Comment: Now I'm kinda curious, if you somehow manage to destruct an object indirectly like that, what happens if you try to use some of that object's methods or data?  Garbage/undefined behavior?

Comment: @GigaWatt: You get undefined behaviour if you access an object after it's been destroyed. (You must also make sure that the destructor doesn't get called a second time - you must never call the destructor directly on a static or automatic object, or one that you're going to `delete`.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Constructors and destructors are somewhat special.  The compiler often
uses different conventions when calling them (e.g. to pass extra hidden
arguments).  If you took the address and saved it somewhere, the
compiler would lose the information that the function is a constructor
or destructor, and would not know to use the special conventions.

Comment: Just curious, is there an actual compiler that uses a different convention for destructor calls?  That is, does anything not treat this as simply a normal member function call?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I've not looked at it recently, but in the past, it was almost univeral, at least when virtual base classes were involved.  The destructor of the virtual base class must be called last, from the destructor of the most derived class; both CFront and Zortech passed a hidden argument to specify whether the destructor was of the most derived class or not.

Comment: Destructors are particularly special if they're `virtual` which can be non-obvious and wouldn't change the type

Comment: So basically the `Test::destructor()` method not only wraps the call to the real destructor, but also all the _magic_ that might be needed in order to invoke it.

That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: As I recall, gcc creates up to four different functions to cover all the different meanings `~type()` can have [virtual base, regular base, et cetera].  Which means not only would you forget the "magic" of the destructor, `&type::~type` would be ambiguous to start with.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose Yes.  Another case of "special conventions": according to context, the names aren't mangled in the same way (since there is actually more than one function).  Thanks for mentioning it.  (In practice, since the exact behavior must vary, the compiler has to do something special.)

Comment: @DennisZickefoose

However, those would all be different functions, with different addresses, each doing something different, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @JamesKanze

Thinking of it, if **I** can safely take the address of a wrapper around the destructor, why doesn't the compiler just implement the destructor itself the way the wrapper is implemented? 

It gets even more obvious if you take inlining into account: in that case `Test::destructor()` will entirely embed `Test::~Test()`, basically rendering the whole point moot.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Fabio: Right, four functions with four addresses... which one does `&Test::~Test` correspond to?  The compiler knows which one to call based on context, which you can't provide in a function pointer signature.  This is the same if the destructors are implemented with hidden parameters.  Which is the same reason it can't just wrap it in a normal function... that normal function would correspond to one specific context, which might not be appropriate for the object you later call it on.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose

I'm not sure I follow you. Once you define a class, you also define whether it has virtual bases and whatnot, so there's just one context, or so it seems to me.

Can you give any specific example of when two different implementations of `Test::~Test()` are invoked and the contexts they are attached to?

Comment: @FabioA. Because within the wrapper, you have a specific context.  (In particular, you know that you are calling the destructor of the most derived class, or you have undefined behavior.)  Each delete and each case where the compiler implicitly calls the destructor also has its context.

Comment: @FabioA. In the implementations which use a hidden argument, that argument is different in a `delete` expression and when the object goes out of scope than it is when the destructor is called from a derived class constructor.

Comment: @JamesKanze

Say you have `Test t`: do `(t.*d)()` and `t.~Test()` achieve the same goal, in any context they are being invoked in (provided they are being invoked in the same context)?

If so, how does taking the address of `Test::~Test()` (if it were possible) differ from taking the address of `Test::destructor()`, for all practical means and purposes?

Comment: @DennisZickefoose same question to you.:)

Comment: @FabioA. The code for `Test::destructor()` can do whatever is necessary to call the destructor, because the compiler can see that the destructor is being called.  If all you have is a pointer to function, and taking the address of a destructor was legal, the compiler wouldn't know whether to generate a call using the conventions of the destructor or the usual conventions.

Comment: @JamesKanze but I already replied to that objection, and you replied to my reply too, see 8 comments above this one.

Comment: @Fabio: in that specific case, `t.~Test()` and `t.destructor()` are equivalent. However, what if instead of `Test t` you had `Test* p`? Then, `p->destructor()` will always call the most-derived-object destructor, even though `*p` may well be a pointer to a some type derived from `Test`. A pointer to the destructor would likely behave the same way, assuming there were some mechanism in place to make the syntax reasonable to start with. This is not safe, and also worthless, so why require implementations to jump through hoops to support it?

Comment: @FabioA. Yes, but you've completely ignored what I said.  A destructor has different calling conventions than an ordinary function.  If I write `p->~T()`, the compiler generates different code than if I write `p->someFunction()`.  If I write `(p->*pmf)()`, and `pmf` contains the address of a destructor, how is the compiler to know that it must generated different code?

Comment: @JamesKanze

I have already answered to that, in the comment I already pointed out above: the compiler can generare the necessary boilerplate code directly inside the destructor, just like it effectively does when inlining the destructor in `Test::destructor()`.

You basically confirmed that when I asked whether `(t.*d)()` and `t.~Test()` achieve the same goal, within any given context.

Comment: @FabioA. A compiler cannot generate the boilerplate code inside the destructor, because the boilerplate code depends on the context where the destructor is called.  It's not always identical.

Comment: @JamesKanze

Then it's not true that `(t.*d)()` and `t.~Test()` achieve the same goal *in any given context*? That's the question I asked before.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose In this specific case, the destructor and the wrapper function are non virtual, therefore `p->destructor()`, `p->~Test()` and `(p->*d)()` all do the same thing, even when p points to a subclass of `Test`. 

The point I'm trying to make is: if I can get the address of the wrapper, and the wrapper acts just like the _real thing_, then why is taking the address of the real thing forbidden?

Comment: @FabioA. The question isn't the results.  The question is how they are called.  The compiler generates different code for `t.~Test()` and `t.someFunction()` (or it may, and compilers in the past have).

Comment: @JamesKanze

I'm afraid we're going in circle. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers talked about the calling convention potentially differing, and this is one reason.

But I think also: It's not clear how *useful* taking the address of a destructor really would be!  What would you use it for?  Calling it is potentially very unsafe -- would you use it for equality comparisons? To determine the exact type of an object, perhaps?  There are other language facilities for that.

Ultimately if the destructor is emitted as a function it does have an address -- but the language considers using that address for *anything*, even equality comparisons so terribly not useful it's just forbidden at the language level.

Technically the compiler could have allowed you to do it -- perhaps forcing it to a void * pointer or something -- but then it would have to be specified which address exactly you would be given.   It's also not always the case that the compiler even emits a destructor for trivial classes as a function -- so taking the address would require it to do so.

It would only be useful for equality comparisons, potentially -- and defining what the equality guarantees are is probably not worth it since other language facilities can potentially achieve the same thing.

Tl;Dr: It's just considered unsafe and not useful, so the language forbids it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the destructor is not guaranteed to exist. If you try the following, and check the disassembly, you'll notice there's no call to a destructor nor is there a destructor function to reference.

https://godbolt.org/z/6nYWf48Gz

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    int a = 3;
};

void fizz() {
    Foo foo;
}

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.~Foo(); // call destructor if exists, otherwise noop
    fizz();
    return 0;
}
```