# Function pointer to object constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a function pointer that points to constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954548/how-to-pass-a-function-pointer-that-points-to-constructor)

Is it possible to pass to a function a function pointer to an object's constructor?

Something like

```
myFunction( myObj() );
```

and how should the function be declared in that case?

```
void myFunction( (*ObjConstructorPointer)() )
```

doesn't work because there's no return type

Comment: What would it mean if you could do that? What would be the result of calling the constructor?

Comment: What are you expecting to be able to do here? If `myObj` is an object of class type, its constructor has already been called when it was created. Why would you want a pointer to its constructor? `myObj()` would just call `operator()` on `myObj`. If `myObj` is a type, then `myObj()` is just creating a temporary object of that type.

Comment: If you want to call the constructor of an object, used placement `new`, which basically exactly calls the constructor with the `this` pointer set to whatever address you give it. The downside is that you have to use templates if you want to parameterise such a function, you can't do it at runtime. Or, you could pass function pointers that take a pointer and call placement `new` on that pointer if you want to do it at runtime, so you could do that at runtime, and create said functions with templates.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is if you wanted to construct objects of a type that is *unknown* inside `myFunction`. If that is the case, and (for simplification) considering that you have a hierarchy, consider using the factory pattern