# C++ load shared library and extract class implementations at runtime on linux platform

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4, shared-libraries

In C++, is it possible to load a shared library at execution time?

I want the user to choose which shared library to be loaded at runtime, without recompiling the whole program.

`dlopen()` is a solution for C, but my program is written is C++/Qt, and the symbol to extract are Qt-style class, is there a more "c++" way to do that.

Comment: What platform is this?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but doesn't inherently relate to [tag:c++] or [tag:qt], it's operating system specific how shared libraries are loaded to your program at runtime. What are your particular problems getting it working from your code?

Comment: What I want to extract from the lib are qt classes, I don't know in qt, there's a mechanism to do that or not.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in Qt using `QLibrary` in two ways. The following example calls a function from a shared library at runtime in two different ways:

```
#include <QLibrary>
#include <QDebug>

class  Dynamic_library
{
public:
    Dynamic_library();
    virtual int sum( int len, int * data );
};

typedef Dynamic_library * (*get_object_func)();
typedef int (*call_sum_func)(int len , int * data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLibrary library( "./dynamic_library" );
    library.load();
    if( !library.isLoaded() )
    {
        qDebug() << "Cannot load library.";
        return 0;
    }
    call_sum_func call_sum = (call_sum_func)library.resolve( "call_sum" );
    if( call_sum )
    {
        //Dynamic_library * obj=get_object();

        int * a=new int[3];
        a[0]=2;
        a[1]=3;
        a[2]=4;
        qDebug() << "sum of 2+3+4' = " << call_sum( 3, a ) <<"\n";

        delete [] a;
    }

    get_object_func get_object = (get_object_func)library.resolve( "get_object" );
    if( get_object )
    {
        Dynamic_library * obj=get_object();

        int * a=new int[3];
        a[0]=7;
        a[1]=8;
        a[2]=9;
        qDebug() << "sum of 7+8+9' = " << obj->sum(3, a );

        delete [] a;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

The code for the shared library is as follows:

```
class DYNAMIC_LIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Dynamic_library
{
public:
    Dynamic_library();
    virtual int sum( int len, int * data );
};

extern "C" Q_DECL_EXPORT Dynamic_library * get_object()
{
     return new Dynamic_library();
}

extern "C" Q_DECL_EXPORT int call_sum(int len, int * data)
{
     return Dynamic_library().sum(len,data);
}


Dynamic_library::Dynamic_library()
{

}

int Dynamic_library::sum( int len, int *data )
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i )
        sum += data[i];

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I have added the code for the shared library to the answer. As you see the extern "C" gives you the possibility to access a C++ class dynamically.

Comment: the "virtual" declaration of member function of "sum" is a must?

Comment: It is necessary to be virtual. Because we declare it and don't define it when we are using it.

Comment: thanks very much, and I also find that I can't retrieve the static members from the class

Answer (score 2):

If the target library itself, or at least its specification, is under your control, then you shouldn't be using `QLibrary` - use the [Qt plugin system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) instead. It doesn't require the call-via-pointer gymnastics otherwise needed.

If you insist on using a `dlopen`-like mechanism, there is nothing C-specific about `QLibrary`. The obvious limitation is that the library that you're trying to open must have been compiled with a C++ compiler that's ABI-compatible to the one you use to compile your own code. On Windows that really means using the same MSVC version.

Apart from that, you'll have to [look up the mangled version of the symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12406668/1329652). Once you've done that, you can call the symbol using a function/method pointer that matches it. This [won't work on constructors/destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954565/1329652), by design. If you wish to create new instances of objects, you'll need a static factory method provided by the library.

If the library doesn't provide factory methods, you can implement a shim library that links to the target library by a generic name and does provide factory methods. You'll still need to call individual methods by function/method pointers.

1. Create a temporary folder.
2. Copy the shim library to the temporary folder.
3. Copy the target library renamed to the generic name, into the temporary folder.
4. Save the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.
5. Prepend the temporary folder to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
6. Open/load the library.
7. Restore the saved value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Of course, you must have the header file for whatever interface the library exposes. It can't be, generally, reconstructed given just a dynamic library file - primarily because the mangled symbols don't have full structural information for the used types. For example, even if you can find a constructor for a given class, you won't know how big is the class instance (its `sizeof`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do what you're describing on most operating systems, but how you do it is dependent on the system and regardless of the system it's definitely a bit more work on your end to make it happen.

The general steps are:

1. load the library
2. for each symbol you're interested in within the library, locate it and store to a variable for later use. (This can be done as-needed, rather than right away.)

For example, in pseudo-code (read: this won't compile!) on a *nix type system, lets assume your shared library has this in it:

```
// I'm declaring this _extern "C"_ to avoid name mangling, making it easier to
// specify a symbol name for dlsym() later
extern "C" int myFunction() {
    return 10;
}
```

Assume this is in a library called libmyFunction.so. Your main application could, for example:

```
{
    void *handle = dlopen("libmyFunction.so", <flags>);
    if (!handle) return; // error: cannot locate the library!

    int (*func)() = (int (*)())dlsym(handle, "myFunction");
    if (!func) return; // error: cannot locate the symbol!

    printf("The function returns: %d\n", func());
}
```

If you need to do this on Windows, the concept is the same but the function calls are different.