# Can I use class type in map<char[2],class> as container?

Tags: c++, xml, dictionary

What I want to do: I load data from a XML file (this goes fine). The XML tells the program to create class instances (from specific different classes, like `Car` or `Plane`) which then will exist within the program. These class instance objects are subclasses of an overarching `Object` base class.

The XML file stores what type of object needs to be created in the form of a number, from which the program will determine which class of object to create.

I could use a `switch` statement and enumerate all types of objects, but this is incredibly taxing on performance when adding loads of instances of objects. So instead, I want a mapping from `char[2]` to the required class. (Note: to the class type itself, not an instance of the class.)

For example, if the XML attribute says `'type=0x01'`, then an object from the class `Car` will be made, while if `'type=0x02`' then a `Plane` object will be made. (Both are kinds of `Object`)

In this way, I want to use a constant map to get this done.  I want to write something like

```
map<char[2],class> ObjectsList = {
     {0x01,Car},
     {0x02,Plane}
     //etc, etc.
}

...
// while loading data from xml file on which objects need to get created,
// an object-tag gives data from 'type' attribute, and the program stores
// it in 'char[2] type';
char[2] type = getattributestufffromxml("type");
ObjectsList[type] newObject = memoryallocator.allocate(sizeof(ObjectsList[type]);
newObject.Init(); //inherited function from Object
```

The idea of this is to create a faster approach rather than sticking with a switch-statement, which is awful when creating hundreds of objects.

What do I need to do to get from the above to something that's valid C++? I do not know how I can store class types in a map. (I get compiler errors such as, 'parameter 2/4 are invalid')

Comment: *Anyone got any idea how I can fix this?* What is wrong with it?

Comment: I added a bit of extra explanation for clarity. The problem is; I want to store  the class type as a reference in the map, so it's easily referenced.

Comment: Are you *intentionally* [slicing your objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) in that map?

Comment: @Generaal Looks more like a case to use `std::map<uint8_t,Vehicle*>` for me.

Comment: @WhozCraig: no, that is not my intention.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: in the map I am not attempting to store the instances of the objects, but rather the object types themselves as a reference.

Comment: @Generaal Yeah, I've got that. Wrote an appropriate answer.

Comment: Have you proved that the big `switch` is slower than a `map` lookup?  What if you nest a switch on each char: `switch (type[0]) { case '0': switch (type[1]) { case '0': return new Car; case '1': return new Plane; /* more 0x cases */ } case '1': switch (type[1]) { /* etc */ } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not know how I can store class types in a map. (I constantly get 'parameter 2/4 are invalid')

Well, a `char[2]` array can't be used as the `std::map::key_type` since it doesn't fulfill the necessary constraints for the [`Compare` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare).
From your initializer list it looks you want a `uint8_t` as key value anyways.

Also you can't store types as values in your map.

Should it be you meant to use function pointers for constructors, [that's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954548/how-to-pass-a-function-pointer-that-points-to-constructor) since constructor and destructor functions are special beasts (no return type not even `void`), and you can't reference to them with a function pointer.

---

I think what you actually need is a `std::map` storing factory functions corresponding to a `enum` like:

```
enum class VehicleTypes : uint8_t {
    CarType = 0x01 ,
    PlaneType = 0x02 ,
}; 

struct Vehicle {
     virtual ~Vehicle() {}
     virtual void Init() = 0;
};

typedef std::function<Vehicle*()> CreateVehicleFn;

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
     virtual void Init() {
         // do anything necessary to init a Car
     }
};

class Plane : public Vehicle {
public:
     virtual void Init() {
         // do anything necessary to init a Plane
};

std::map<VehicleTypes,CreateVehicleFn> CreatorFnList = 
     { { VehicleTypes::CarType, []() { return new Car(); } } ,
       { VehicleTypes::PlaneType, []() { return new Plane(); } }
     };
```

The latter map initialization list isn't much more code to write than you provided in your (pseudo-) code example.
If you want to get rid of the boiler plate stuff, and think it's worth to obfuscate your code, you can still use a macro:

```
#define Create(classtype) []() { return new classtype(); }

std::map<VehicleTypes,CreateVehicleFn> CreatorFnList = 
     { { VehicleTypes::CarType, Create(Car) } ,
       { VehicleTypes::PlaneType, Create(Plane) }
     };
```

---

You can use it then later to create new instances depending on the key parameter:

```
Plane* plane = dynamic_cast<Plane*>(CreateVehicleFn[VehicleTypes::PlaneType]());
if(plane) {
    plane->Init();
}
```

---

To provide clear ownership semantics even consider to use a `std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>` to pass around the new instances from factory to client:

```
typedef std::function<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>()> CreateVehicleFn;

std::map<VehicleTypes,CreateVehicleFn> CreatorFnList = 
     { { VehicleTypes::CarType, []() { return make_unique<Car>(); } } ,
       { VehicleTypes::PlaneType, []() { return make_unique<Plane>(); } }
     };
```

---

The syntax for usage is much the same as for my 1st sample:

```
std::unique_ptr<Plane> plane = CreateVehicleFn[VehicleTypes::PlaneType]();
if(plane.get()) {
    plane->Init();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a class is a (compile-type) definition, not a (run-time) data object.  So you can't store a class.

However, you can declare a Factory type, and store instances of the factory.

For example:

```
class Factory
{
     virtual std::unique_ptr<Object> createInstance(std::string description);
}

class CarFactory : public Factory
{
     std::unique_ptr<Object> createInstance(std::string description) override;
}
class PlaneFactory : public Factory
{
     std::unique_ptr<Object> createInstance(std::string description) override;
}
```

We then store factories:

```
std::map<const char[2],Factory*> factories = {
     {"00", new CarFactory},
     {"01", new PlaneFactory},
     //...
}
```

You might be able to make a generic factory:

```
template<typename T>
class VehicleFactory : public Factory
{
     std::unique_ptr<Object> createInstance(std::string description) override
     { return std::make_unique<T>(description); }
}

std::map<int,Factory*> factories = {
     {"00", new VehicleFactory<Car>},
     {"01", new VehicleFactory<Plane>},
     //...
}
```

Once we have a factory, we can use it:

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> createVehicle(const char type[2], std::string description)
{
    // error handling is an exercise for the reader
    return factories[type]->createInstance(description);
}
```

Comment: Why not just wait and post a complete answer?

Comment: @Toby Bit of _old school style_.

Comment: @Nathan - main reason is because I came here from reviewing Low Quality questions, and it already had three close votes.  I wanted to show that a good answer existed despite the unclear question, and to not lose too much work if the question was closed.  A secondary aim is to save the time of other answerers thinking of writing something very similar (although I wouldn't normally post a half-answer for that reason alone).

Comment: @πάντα - yes, I know; I was hoping this would be clearer for the questioner.  I've upvoted your answer, and I think that both answers together give a pretty good picture.

Comment: @TobySpeight _"and I think that both answers together give a pretty good picture"_ Sure.