# Using class constructor as callable object

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class C {
public:
    C() {}
};

template<typename T>
void func(T f) {}

int main() {
    func(C);
}
```

How to fix the compilation error "2.cpp:9:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
         func(C);"?

Passing class as parameter seems ridiculous, but I want to compile function like thread, since "thread(C)" works fine:

```
#include <thread>

class C {
public:
    C() {}
};

template<typename T>
void func(T f) {}

int main() {
    std::thread(C);
}
```

Comment: You probably want `func(C());`

Comment: @AmiTavory I added an explanation why I need to pass C

Comment: It's not clear what are trying to accomplish. Can you post working code that uses `thread(C);`?

Comment: @RSahu added the code with thread

Comment: Note that `std::thread(C);` is not a function call, as `std::thread` is a type - it's a declaration of local variable called `C` of type `std::thread`. Like `int x;`, `int(((x)));` or `void (*x)();`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, [one cannot take address of a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954548) in C++. Meaning, you cannot simply take "a pointer to constructor" and use it as a functor (like you'd do with free function or member function).

You actually cannot "pass a class" as a parameter, because C++ core does not have reflection and if you get "a class" in runtime, you cannot do anything with it. You can only "pass a class" as a template parameter.

What you can do, though, is simply use lambda function which will call the corresponding constructor:

```
class C {
public:
    C() {}
};

template<typename T>
void func(T f) {
  auto c_instance = f();
}

int main() {
    func([](){ return C(); });
}
```

Note that you still do not pass anything in runtime - return type of the lambda `[](){ return C(); }` is known in compile-time, therefore the type of `auto c_instance` is also known in compile-time.

However, I think that if you don't need to pass any other factories for `C`  into `func`, simply creating the instance inside `func` would be clearer:

```
class C {
public:
    C() {}
};

template<typename T>
void func() {
  T c_instance;
}

int main() {
    func<C>();
}
```

---

## Regarding `std::thread(c);`

```
std::thread(C);
```

is not a function call. `std::thread` is a type. Therefore, it declares a local variable named `C`. Using

```
auto a = std::thread(C);
```

should produce a similar compiler error.

Comment: @Yuriy because `std::thread(C)` is not a function call. `std::thread` is a type. Therefore, it's local variable declaration. Try adding `C.join()` after that line and you'll see that yourself.

Comment: @Yuriy `std::thread::thread` is a template, see case (3) here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Comment: @RichardCritten, this template isn't used in this case, the first definition is used.

Comment: @Yuriy was responding to your _"Then, why it works with thread?"_

Comment: @RichardCritten, yes, definition 3 isn't used in this case