# What is foo*(*)?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

In a project, I came accross following line of code.

```
::std::unordered_map<std::string, Channel*(*)(Module*, const Parameters&)>;
```

Does anyone know what Channel*(*) could mean? Is is the same as Channel**? It seems confusing and overcomplicated to me.

The Channel constructor looks like this:

```
Channel(Module* module, const util::Parameters& parameters);
```

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
Channel*(*)(Module*, const Parameters&)
```

Is pointer to a function that takes a `Module*` and a `const Parameters&` as argument and returns a `Channel*`.

For more details see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Function pointers are look rather intimidating, and an alias makes using them much simpler:

```
using fun = Channel*(Module*, const Parameters&);
fun* x = &some_function_with_right_signature;
// or
::std::unordered_map<std::string,fptr>;
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding giving aliases to pointers. Non pointer aliases are easier to read, and you don't hide the pointers: `using fun = ret(args); fun* x = &some;`

Comment: @eerorika in general thats my rule of thumb, though it never occured to me to apply it for function pointers. Have to think about it ;)

Comment: So it is a function pointer to a constructor. From what I understand, it can be used to instantiate an object. Is it destroyed automatically when it is destroyed? If not, how can it be destroyed?

Comment: @uro1012 no, constructors are rather special. It is a pointer to a free function. It could be a `Channel* foo(Module*, const Parameters&);` which calls the constructor and returns a pointer to the constructed object

Comment: @uro1012 see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/954565/4117728