# Indirect perfect forwarding via function pointer?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, forwarding-reference

Lets consider ordinary perfect forwarding:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(Test const&) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    Test(Test&&)      { std::cout << "move\n"; }
};

void test(Test)
{ }

template <typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    test(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "expect: copy\n";
    Test t;
    f(t);
    std::cout << "expect: move\n";
    f(Test());
    return 0;
}
```

So far everything is fine. But if we now introduce a function pointer I get the problem that I seem not to be able to declare [*universal* (forwarding) references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers):

```
    decltype(&f<Test>) ptr = &f<Test>;
    // above produces ordinary r-value references
    // making below fail already on compilation:
    ptr(t);
```

Template function pointers get problematic as well:

```
template <typename T>
void(*ptr)(T&& t) = &f<T>; // again resolved to r-value reference
```

At first, they resolve to pure r-value reference as well, additionally they define a *bunch* of pointers instead of a single one, making the approach unusable within class scope:

```
class C
{
    template <typename T>
    void(*ptr)(T&& t); // fails (of course...)
};
```

So question now is: Is it possible at all to have indirect perfect forwarding via function pointers?

Admitted, already fearing the answer is *'no'* (and currently falling back to l-value references), but still in hope of having overlooked something somewhere...

Comment: A function pointer needs to point to a particular function.  function templates are not functions, so you can't point to them.

Comment: you cannot point to overload of functions either.

Comment: the template parameter has to be deduced for perfect forwarding to work

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm aware of that – but I can of *specialisatoins*, see my `decltype` approach, solely that I received r-value reference exclusively. Hm... – so then seems as if *universal* references do not exist at all but are just a hypothetical concept for explanation – while actual reference type is resolved by deduction just as usual, with default to r-value reference. If so (?), then clear why I cannot (unfortunately...).

Comment: @appleapple Well, one actually can, requires a cast, though ;) `void f(int) { } void f(double) { } auto ptr = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(&f);`

Comment: @Aconcagua then you're point to one function, not overloads, though.

Comment: @appleapple That would have been totally fine in my case – provided that [universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) existed as separate type. Seems, though, as they actually do *not* (just being used for explanation), thus my attempts (obviously) failing...

Comment: "... existed as separate type..." afaik universal references didnt "exist" until Scott raised some attention to this particular use of deducing a `T&&` function argument type. Following that a new name ("forwarding reference") was given to them, to provide clarity/better explanations but its not really some new type of references.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sure, I see *now*, it's been nothing more than a red herring – and that's not the way I *would* have needed them to exist ;) Maybe worth a proposition for next standard or just too exotic the use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background of the question is a mis-reading of Scott Meyer's [article about forwarding references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (called *'universal references'* there).

The article gave the impression of such forwarding references existing as a separate type *in parallel* to ordinary l-value and r-value references. This is not the case, though, instead it is a hypothetical construct to explain special deduction rules that exist if template parameters serve as function parameter types.

As such a type does not exist in consequence it is not possible to declare a function pointer using that type, proving indirect perfect forwarding via function pointer impossible to realise.

Answer (score 3):

A *forwarding reference* is not only a hypothetical concept. It is the name given to a specific kind of rvalue reference which has special deduction rules in template argument deduction.

Specifically according to [[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp#deduct.call-3.sentence-3):

> A *forwarding reference* is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])). If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

Except for this special rule (and one other in [[temp.deduct.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp#deduct.type-10.sentence-2)), a forwarding reference behaves just like any other rvalue reference.

In particular when providing a template argument for `T`, there is no template argument deduction happening and substitution is performed directly. In substitution the usual reference collapsing rules are applied.

So `f<Test>` will yield the function parameter `Test&&` which is a rvalue reference and `f<Test&>` will yield the function parameter `Test&` (collapsed from `&&` being applied to `Test&`).

These are also the template arguments that would be deduced for a rvalue argument and a lvalue argument in a function call without explicit template arguments. If the reference was not a forwarding reference, then `T` could never be deduced to a reference and the function parameter would always be a rvalue reference after substitution. The special adjustment of `A` mentioned in the quote allows `T` to be deduced to an lvalue reference type, so that the collapsing rules will result in an lvalue reference function parameter as well.

Forwarding references can only exist in templates. A function or specialization of a template cannot have a forwarding reference. They are not somehow a different category of reference from rvalue/lvalue references. They work in templates only by deducing to different types for different value categories of arguments and produce distinct specializations for each value category.

---

So, since a function pointer must point to a *function*, not a function template, which of the two specializations for the value category of the argument to choose, has to be decided when taking the function pointer.

If deduction of any kind is expected, then a function pointer cannot offer that. Instead a lambda or functor type should be used which can perform deduction and can choose the function or function template specialization to call based on value category.

Comment: They are hypothetical. All that exists are special deduction rules for – but they do not exist as yet another *type*, in parallel to l-value and r-value references – which is the impression Scot Meyer's [article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) gave, but just a red herring, as I learned in the meanwhile...

Answer (score 2):

The first example uses template argument deduction and [reference collapsing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) to compute the correct type. When you explicitly supply the template arguments this disables deduction and the supplied type is substituted directly, resulting in the rvalue reference.

Comment: Well, and obviously those [universal/forwarding references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)  (the red herring...) are just a hypothetical concept for explanation then, but in reality they do *not* exist – sadly enough as it means indirect perfect forwarding is simply *not possible* :(

Answer (score 0):

Perfect forwarding requires the template argument to be deduced. A function pointer can only point to a single function, not to a set of overloads, and not to a function template.

You can get a function pointer to either the r-value reference instantiation:

```
decltype(&f<Test&&>) ptr1 = &f<Test&&>;
ptr1(Test());     // output: move
```

or the l-value instantiation:

```
decltype(&f<Test&>) ptr2 = &f<Test&>;
ptr2(t);          // output: copy
```

But not to both at the same time. `ptr1` and `ptr2` are pointers to functions of different type.

When you want something to hold not just a single function but more than one overload you can use a type with member functions. For example with a lambda expression:

```
auto fw = [](auto&& t){ test(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)); };
fw(t);          // output: copy
fw(Test());     // output: move
```

Comment: Well, all that about templates is fully clear. Red herring was Scot Meyer's [article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) giving the impression that such a thing like a forwarding reference existed as a *type* – in parallel to r-value references and l-value references. The inexistence then is core to perfect forwarding failing via function pointers...

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah, this answer doesnt add something new. imho the biggest issue that went wrong with "forwarding" / "universal" references is that Scott was rather sucessful in popularizing the term "universal reference" but that wasnt adopted in favor of "forwarding references". Now having two terms for the same adds confusion. Also because Scotts articles on the subject still call them "universal" and dont mention the more "official" term

Comment: Well, the naming is not the problem. I don't care *in given context* how they actually are called. I misinterpreted the article such that I assumed them to exist as separate type *in parallel* to ordinary l- and r-value references. Well, I learned now, totally wrong... Thus I can't declare a function pointer using it, thus no perfect forwarding passing through them...

Comment: Seems, though, that this misinterpretation isn't read clearly from my question, thus all those answers about not being able to create function pointers to templates (which I'm well aware of...).