# How do I describe a constructor with boost::describe?

Tags: c++, reflection, template-meta-programming, boost-describe

The boost::describe library works when defining reflection info for member functions and variables, but is it possible to describe constructors?

Comment: To be useful, the description would have to be able to point to said constructor. At which point you run into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954548/how-to-pass-a-function-pointer-that-points-to-constructor -- use a static factory method instead?

Comment: I'd love to use a static factory method, but I'm using boost describe for types that are defined elsewhere.

And I'm not necessarily interested in pointing to a constructor.  If I know the type signature of the parameters, I can call construct_from_tuple.

Comment: So, you want to add a fictitious method name (e.g. `__construct`) pointing nowhere with the right signature to the description? Probably possible if you look under the hood at what happens for other methods.